# Retrieving from ftp dirs with wildcards

Tags: ftp, wget, curl, lftp

What is the most efficient way to retrieve all relevant data from ftp if the address of said data can be specified with wildcards as below:

```
ftp://ftp.some.site.gov/data/directory/only/*/these/*/*files.gz
```